# Getting list of ports when using serial communication C#

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am aware of the syntax used to get the port names

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

The output is not quite as expected. When I go on to print the strings, the output is;

```
System.String[]
```

I am probably missing something. Kindly help...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the array object not the strings in the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<ports.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ports[i]);
}
```

Or use:

```
foreach(String port in ports)
{
     Console.WriteLine(port);
}
```